# Underscore find a value in multiarray

Tags: underscore.js

I'm very new at underscore I'll thank any help.

I'm trying to return "peopleAttending" in room like "2-0-110" not necessarily first in the object "rooms" or , which is similar: "peopleAttending" in room  where "id" = "2-0-110"

```
{ 
  "2-0-110": { 
      name:"room-2-0-110",
      id:"2-0-110",
      people:["2,3"],
      peopleLimit:50,
      peopleAttending:["9,5562,5614"] 
    },
  "2-0-54": { 
      name:"room-2-0-54",
      id:"2-0-54",
      people:["4,5"],
      peopleLimit:40,
      peopleAttending:["1000,3334,434545"]
    }
}
```

I try many thing but I think using something like this would be the most clean method, but I did not manage to get what I need , can't anyone explain and help a bit with this I want to achieve?

```
var roomPeopleAttending = _.find(rooms, function (room) { return 'peopleAttending' in room });
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no need in underscore, you can manage in with plain JS

```
function getAttending(roomId, rooms) { 
    /*
     * just return data, as no modification needs 
     * getAttending('2-0-110') => ["9,5562,5614"] 
     */
    return (rooms[roomId] || {}).peopleAttending;
};
```

You may be intrested in **lodash** `.get` method.